# Formating Active admin table data with a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

i have a resource defined for active admin like so. All I want to do is format the phone with the rails *number_to_phone* function. However either the documentation is not clear, or my still limited ruby/rails vocabulary is lacking the proper term.

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Voter do
  menu :label => "Voters"
  index do
    column :id
    column :last_name
    column :first_name
    column :middle_name
    column :suffix
    column :address
    column :city
    column :state
    column :zip
    column :zip4
    column :phone
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

per [Rails Cast #284](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin)

```
column :phone, :phone do |voter|
      number_to_phone voter.phone
    end
```